# Specifying Blocks to Be Played?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, chatfuel

I've read through the docs (really, it's just a small subset of examples) here and I can't find the answer:

https://docs.chatfuel.com/api/json-api/json-api

I'd really like to be able to specify "Typing" in a JSON response through the JSON API.  I've got some Typing blocks of different lenghts but, as I understand it, you can't specify blocks to be displayed in your JSON response?

I've tried specifying the "block_names" of pre-defined Typing blocks in various ways, as message objects, after message objects, etc.

Example code:

```
{
 "messages": 
 [
  {
   "text": "Woohoo!  We found your app!"
  },
  {
   "block_names": "Typing Medium"
  },
  {
   "text": "Our system shows your status as 'Denied'."
  }
 ]
}
```

I would expect the user to see the first text, then typing for a few seconds, then the next message.

As I stated, I've tried to specify block_names in several ways and cannot get the desired outcome.

If you can't ask Chatfuel to show a block from your JSON response, is there a way to simply specify to show Typing (which is I think the #1 reason one would need this)?  Maybe like:

```
{
 "messages": 
 [
  {
   "text": "Woohoo!  We found your app!"
  },
  {
   "typing": 1900
  },
  {
   "text": "Our system shows your status as 'Denied'."
  }
 ]
}
```